# How to compare switch statement control expression with its patterns in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, switch-statement, compare, expression

I have a tried this and it does not work:

```
    let value1 = 12
    let sumOfOtherValues = 10 + 1 + 24

    switch value1 {
    case let (value1,sumOfOtherValues) where (value1 > sumOfOtherValues):
         break;
    case value1..>sumOfOtherValues:
         break;
    default:
         breaK;
    }
```

I would really like to make this in a switch statement and not in an if statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is this what you need? (I don't understand your need for `value1..>sumOfOtherValues`

```
let value1 = 12
let sumOfOtherValues = 10 + 1 + 24

switch value1 {
case _ where sumOfOtherValues > value1:
    println("case 1")
    //break //it's not mandatory. 
    fallthrough //Without this code, this will stop here if the switch match this case. If you want that your switch continue to search, add 'fallthrough' at the end of each case
case _ where value1 > sumOfOtherValues:
    println("case 2")
    break
default:
    break
}
```